# app plays sounds on silent mode - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, wav, avaudiosession

I have a function in my app to play sound effects. I was pretty sure that it used to be when my phone was on silent mode the sound effects wouldn't play. But now they do. I'm not sure why and need to know if its a glitch with my phone or something wrong with my code.

```
        func playSound (Sound: String, Type: String) {

        //Prepare the sound file name & extension
        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(Sound, ofType: Type)!)

        //Preparation to play
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        //Play audio

        var error: NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use following audio session categories, sounds will not be muted on iOS: `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`,`AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord`,`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.
Use `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` or `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` if you don't want the sound effects play on silence mode. Or, just don't touch the audio session (do not register one), by default your sounds will be muted on silence mode.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Could you post exactly the code you used please? I used the following: try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers);
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true);
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL);